# my C program crashing for an unseen reason

Tags: c

So my program is meant to be a little command line but it keeps crashing:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>    

void main()
{    
    char cmd;
    for(;;)
    {
        fgets(cmd,255,stdin);
        if (strstr(cmd,"CD")!=NULL )
        {
            cmd +=2;
            SetCurrentDirectory(cmd);
        }
        else
        {
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

the compiler output is lvalue expected.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.  Or fix the ones you do get.

Comment: Did it compile successfully?

Comment: perhaps you would like `cmd` to be a character array. `char cmd[255];`

Comment: Compiler warnings tell you where you've made errors, which there are here

Comment: if i use [255] it causes errors on line 15

Comment: Why cmd +=2; And how do you plan to exit the loop?

Comment: i use +=2 to get rid of CD and leave example /users\username

Comment: Edit the question to show the actual code and add the compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking to do something like this:

```
void main()
{    
    char cmd[255]; // this allocate a character array to store the command in
    for(;;)
    {
        fgets(cmd,255,stdin); // get the characters from stdin and store them in the cmd character array with a max length of 255
        if ( strncmp(cmd, "CD ", 3) == 0 ) // check if the first three characters are "CD "
        {
            SetCurrentDirectory(&cmd[3]); // pass the string not including the first 3 charcters, which should be "CD "
        }
        else
        {
            system(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. :)

Comment: Happy to help. If you are looking to learn C you should spend time and try to figure out what each line does and why. It would be very useful to you. Why did using `char cmd;` not work but using `char cmd[255];` work? What's the difference?

Comment: @darrenthebozz :  Consider also using `fgets( cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin ) ;`.  Also beware that a user may enter additional whitespace between the command and its the argument.

Comment: Since this is windows, the user might have entered `CD` or `cd` or `Cd` or `cD`  the posted code only handles the `CD`  Also, in windows the user could have placed no white space between the `cd` and the new directory name

Comment: Lots of improvements you could make to make it like windows, based on the OP I think it is best to keep it simple so the OP can focus on things like differentiating between `char cmd;` and `char cmd[255];` and not worry about extra white space and such yet.